# Converting Python statement into string

Tags: python

I got a situation I have to generate a if condition based on item configured in my configuration json file.

So once the if statement converted into a string I want that to run by eval .

This is what I am trying for that.
Here is what flags and set_value look like

My json

```
 "EMAIL_CONDITION":
        {
           "TOXIC_THRESOLD":"50",
           "TOXIC_PLATFORM_TODAY":"0",
           "TOXIC_PRS_TODAY":"0",
           "Explanation":"select any or all 1 for TOXIC_Thresold 2 for TOXIC_PLATFORM 3 for toxic_prs ",
           "CONDITION_TYPE":["1","2"]

        },
        "email_list":{
          "cc":["abc@def.t"],
          "to":["abc@def.net"]
        }
```

The Python

`CONDITION_TYPE` is a variable where values can be either all, any or 1,2 ,2,3, or 1,3
1 stands for toxic index 2 for platform and 3  for toxic prs

But  the idea is going forward any number of parameters can be added so I wanted to make the if condition generic so that can take any number of conditions simply just wanted to avoid to many if else. all and any i have already handaled its straight forward but this is  variable number so only else part snippet given

```
flags['1'] = toxic_index
flags['2'] = toxic_platform
flags['3'] = toxic_prs

set_value['1'] = toxic_index_condition
set_value['2'] = toxic_platform_condition
set_value['3'] = toxic_pr_condition



   else:
       condition_string = 'if '
       for val,has_more in lookahead(conditions):
           if has_more:
               condition_string = str(condition_string+ str(flags[val] >= set_value[val])+ str('and') )
           else:

               condition_string = str(condition_string+ str(flags[val] >= set_value[val]) + str(':') )
       print str(condition_string)
```

I do understand that most of them are variable so I am getting the response like

```
if False and False:
```

Instead of False I wanted to get the real condition(basically like `condition_string+ str(flags[val] >= set_value[val])`  ) based on that I can send mail.

I am not able to do that as I am getting False and False.

Please suggest me a best solution for it.

Comment: This is impossible to understand without an example input file.  We have no idea what `conditions` looks like and the various `val` and `flags` things aren't defined, either.  Please try to reduce this into a [mcve]

Comment: @tripleee updated pls check

Comment: What sort of conditions do you want to get instead? It's still difficult to understand what you're looking for without seeing an example JSON config file, too.

Comment: @all please check now I made required changes